# ubuntu LAMP server can't create new .conf file and configure

Tags: server, apache2, php, configuration, lamp

I have the *LAMP server* on **Ubuntu 14.04**. I came to know about the php [laravel framework](http://laravel.com/).
So I just installed laravel by going from [this](http://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/getting-started-with-laravel-4-on-ubuntu-installation-and-configuration/) link.

I just made copy the `000-default.conf` file from the path `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and renamed the file as `projects.local.conf` and changed the code inside it as the referenced link shows and made changes the hosts file from `/etc/hosts` as like what the referenced link.

I went through the total tutorial step by step and everything worked fine.
Now I just decided to remove the `laravel` folder and change the installation path.

So to do that I just removed the folder and removed the `projects.local.conf` file from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Now again I just copied the `000-default.conf` and renamed the copied file as `laravel.dev.conf` and made necessary changes as per the link. Like in the `laravel.dev.conf`

I made my code like this

```
<VirtualHost laravel.dev>

    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAlias laravel.dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/projects

    <Directory /var/www/projects/>
        Options -Indexes
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

`sudo a2ensite laravel.dev.conf`

Now when I tried to restart the server by doing 
 `sudo service apache2 restart`
 It showed me error like this:

```
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/projects.local.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Whenever I am trying to create a new `.conf` file and again removing that and doing restart the server . It is showing the error for the `.conf` file which has been deleted recently.
I have tried many times but its not working at all.

So can someone tell me how to solve this issue? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> So to do that I just removed the folder and removed the `projects.local.conf` file from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

You removed the configuration file, but did not disable the site:

```
sudo a2dissite projects.local
# or
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/projects.local.conf
```